# Sphinx Documentation with different separated subjects

Tags: directory, python-sphinx, glob, read-the-docs, toctree

I'm trying to build kind of a dashboard in the index with one tile per subject. Each subject will later have its own folder in `source` with it's own md files.

I want each subject to be disconnected to the others. So the `previous` button should no go to another subject.

The structure should be something like this:
[image]
First there is an overview with all subjects, then there is a subpage with one toctree per subject and then each document has its own normal view.

Does anyone have an idea how I would go about it?

Currently I build the index like that, but this doesn't separate the files:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :name: mastertoc
   :caption: Example Files:
   :glob:

   introduction
   examples

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :name: Subject1
   :caption: Subject1:
   :glob:

   Subject1/*

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :name: Subject2
   :caption: Subject2:
   :glob:

   Subject2/*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your request, you want to have an index page for each subject, too. We do that for Pyramid in a couple of places, like so:

### [docs/index.rst](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blame/1.9-branch/docs/index.rst#L155-L160)

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :glob:

   api/index
   api/*
```

### [docs/api/index.rst](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blame/1.9-branch/docs/api/index.rst#L8-L12)

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :glob:

   *
```

Here it is in action:

https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/#api-documentation

The first link goes to:

https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/index.html